# When I exit my my Settings menu and re-enter it the OnPreferenceChangedListener stops working

Tags: java, android, preferences

This is my first time posting on here, so if my problem is not clear and more information is needed please let me know.

I am making an app on android, and I have made a Preference activity. When I change the value of the preferences, the summery updates to the value of the preference. It works Great when I first Enter it, but the program stops updating the summary if I exit and then re-enter.

I tried overriding the OnResume for the Activity that has the Listener to re-register the onPreferenceChangedListener, but it didn't work.

MainActivity.java

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.preference.PreferenceManager;

import com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton;

import edu.christiansen.character_creator.Classes.CharacterV5;
import edu.christiansen.character_creator.data.globalVars;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener {

    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.main_toolbar);
                  .
                  .
                  .

        setupSharedPreferences();

                  .
                  .
                  .



    }
                  .
                  .
                  .
    private void setupSharedPreferences() {
        sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
        sharedPreferences.registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onSharedPreferenceChanged(SharedPreferences sharedPreferences, String key) {
        if (key.equals("ppTogp") || key.equals("gpTosp") || key.equals("spTocp")) {
            SettingsFrag.Instance.CheckSetEdit(key);
        } else if(key.equals("roll_type")){
            RollSettings.Instance.setRollScreen(key);
        } else if (key.equals("min_roll") || key.equals("min_points")){
            RollSettings.Instance.CheckSetEdit(key);
        }

    }

 @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        androidx.preference.PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this)
                .registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        androidx.preference.PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this)
                .unregisterOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(this);
    }
}
```

SettingFrag.java

```
public class SettingsFrag extends PreferenceFragmentCompat {

    public static SettingsFrag Instance;

    private PreferenceScreen preferenceScreen;

    Preference RollPreference;

    private String Lastppconvertion;
    private String Lastgpconvertion;
    private String Lastspconvertion;

    public SettingsFrag() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }


    @Override
    public void onCreatePreferences(Bundle bundle, String s) {
        addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.fragment_settings);
        RollPreference = findPreference("roll_preferences");

        preferenceScreen = this.getPreferenceScreen();
        if (Instance == null){
            Instance = this;
        }
        UpdateEditTextPreferences("ppTogp");
        UpdateEditTextPreferences("gpTosp");
        UpdateEditTextPreferences("spTocp");
    }

    public void CheckSetEdit(String key){
        EditTextPreference edp = (EditTextPreference) preferenceScreen.findPreference(key);

        if(RollSettings.isInteger(edp.getText())){
            UpdateEditTextPreferences(key);
            setValue(key, edp.getText());
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Invalid Entry - Please Try again", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            edp.setText(getValue(key));
        }
    }

    private void setValue(String key, String text){
        if (key.equals("ppTogp")){
            Lastppconvertion = text;
        } else if (key.equals("gpTosp")){
            Lastgpconvertion = text;
        } else if (key.equals("spTocp")){
            Lastspconvertion = text;
    }
    }

    private String getValue(String key){
        if (key.equals("ppTogp")){
            return Lastppconvertion;
        } else if (key.equals("gpTosp")){
            return Lastgpconvertion;
        } else if (key.equals("spTocp")){
            return Lastspconvertion;
        }
        return "";
    }

    public void UpdateEditTextPreferences(String key){
        EditTextPreference etp = (EditTextPreference) preferenceScreen.findPreference(key);
        preferenceScreen.findPreference(key).setSummary(etp.getText());
    }
```

I have no Idea why It is not working, because the change listener should be start back up when I navigate back to the main activity. Any Insight on this Problem would be helpful.

Thank you

Comment: could you please post yout logcat error code

Comment: I figured it out. I had the onPrefrenceChangeListener set to a singleton instance of my Preference menu (this was a workaround for another bug) and when a new instance was created it would update the singleton but not the new instance. I have redesigned the code without the singleton and it works great.